# $A$ has a min polynomial of deg $k$. Given a $g(t)$ s.t. $g(A)$ is invertible, there exists $h(x)$ of degree $\leq k-1$ s.t. $g(A)^{-1} = h(A)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

A square matrix $A$ has a minimal polynomial of degree $k$. Given a polynomial $g(t)$ s.t. $g(A)$ is invertible, prove that there exists a polynomial $h(x)$ of degree $\leq k-1$ s.t. $g(A)^{-1} = h(A)$.

I'm pretty sure the answer is somewhere along these lines:
We label $B = g(A)^{-1}$. Looking at the characteristic polynomial of $B$, $b(t)$, we can divide by the minimal polynomial of $A$, $m(t)$ and get:

$b(t) = m(t) \cdot k+r(t)$.
Plugging in $A$ we get:

$b(A) = r(A)$, where $deg(r) \leq k-1$. Now I'm pretty sure that $r=h$, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $F$ be the field, we are working over. We have $g(A)^{-1} \in F[g(A)] \subset F[A]$. All elements of $F[A]$ fulfill the desired property.

I will explain this answer a little bit: If $M$ is any square matrix, you can think of $F[M]$ as the ring of all polynomial expressions in $M$. Note that, if $M$ has a minimal polynomial of degree $d$, every such expression can be reduced to a expression of degree smaller $d$, using polynomial division (as you did in your post).

Now lets assume $M$ to be invertible. It is very easy to show that the constant term of the minimal polynomial of $M$ is non-zero. From an equation
$$M^d + a_{d-1}M^{d-1} + \dotsb + a_1M+ a_0=0$$
with $a_0 \neq 0$, we can easily see that $M^{-1}$ can be written as a polynomial expression in $M$. (This - as I did above - can be written $M^{-1} \in F[M]$)

Now we should apply this to our situation: $g(A)$ is invertible, hence $g(A)^{-1}$ is a polynomial expression in $g(A)$, in particular this is a polynomial expression in $A$ (This is what $F[g(A)]\subset F[A]$ refers to). As explained above, such an expression can be assumed to have lower degree than the minimal polynomial. This is exactly what we wanted to show.

Comment: I'm not really sure what the elements of $F[A]$ are or why this is correct.

Comment: I have added some explaination.

Comment: Great answer, thanks a lot!